# How to make two or more slideshows inside tooltips work on the same HTML page?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, slideshow

I have two slideshows made in pure CSS in an html page, each one is inside its own tooltip but one of them (Piediluco) doesn't work properly because its images doesn't slide correctly.

```css
body {
background-color: #000000;
}

.tooltip, .tooltip2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 400px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #5790ce;
}

.tooltip:hover .info, .tooltip:focus .info,
.tooltip2:hover .info2, .tooltip2:focus .info2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.info, .info2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -380px;
  left: 95px;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: justify;
  cursor: text;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.info:before, .info2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 0;
}

.info:after, .info2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 378px;
  right: 494px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background: #8d7200;
}

#i1, #i2, #i3, #i4,
#i12, #i22, #i32, #i42 { 
  display: none;
}

.container, .container2 {
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 120px;
 padding-bottom: 38%;
 user-select: none;
 background-color: #1c1c1c;
}

.container .slide_img,
.container2 .slide_img2 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.container .slide_img .img,
.container2 .slide_img2 .img2 {
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
}

.container .slide_img .caption,
.container2 .slide_img2 .caption2 {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 46px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 14px;
 background-color: rgba(242,242,242,.5);
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.lblp, .lbln, .lblp2, .lbln2 {
 width: 12%;
 height: 22%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 40%;
 background-color: rgba(242,242,242,.3);
 z-index: 99;
 transition: background-color 1s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.lbln, .lbln2 {
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.lblp, .lblp2 {
 left: 0;
 border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.lblp:hover, .lbln:hover,
.lblp2:hover, .lbln2:hover {
 background-color: rgba(242,242,242,.1);
}

.prev, .prev2 {
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(244, 244, 244,.9);
 font-size: 40pt;
 padding: 0 0 15px 20px;
 margin: 0;
 top: 25%;
 transition: color 1s;
}

.next, .next2 {
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(244, 244, 244,.9);
 font-size: 40pt;
 padding: 0 0 15px 25px;
 margin: 0;
 top: 25%;
 transition: color 1s;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover,
.prev2:hover, .next2:hover {
 color: rgba(244, 244, 244,1);
}

.slide_img, .slide_img2 {
 z-index: -1;
}
 
#i1:checked ~ #one,
#i2:checked ~ #two,
#i3:checked ~ #three,
#i4:checked ~ #four,
#i12:checked ~ #one2,
#i22:checked ~ #two2,
#i32:checked ~ #three3,
#i42:checked ~ #four2 {
 z-index: 9;
 animation: scroll 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes scroll{
 0%{ opacity:.4;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}

.text, .text2 {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 17px 35px 17px;
  color: #8d7200;
}

.more, .more2 {
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 215px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: green;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 2px solid green;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.more:hover, .more:focus,
.more2:hover, .more2:focus {
 background-color: green;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="void(0);" class="tooltip">Trasimeno
 <div class="info">
   <div class="container">
     <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked>
     <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images">
     <input type="radio" id="i3" name="images">
     <input type="radio" id="i4" name="images">
       
   <div class="slide_img" id="one">
     <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/W5E69l9.jpg">
     <span class="caption">...................</span>
     <label class="lblp" for="i4"><span class="prev">&#x2039;</span></label>
     <label class="lbln" for="i2"><span class="next">&#x203a;</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="slide_img" id="two">
     <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/eGbNeOB.jpg">
     <span class="caption">...................</span>
     <label class="lblp" for="i1"><span class="prev">&#x2039;</span></label>
     <label class="lbln" for="i3"><span class="next">&#x203a;</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="slide_img" id="three">
     <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/hp2OiNB.jpg">
     <span class="caption">...................</span>
      <label class="lblp" for="i2"><span class="prev">&#x2039;</span></label>
     <label class="lbln" for="i4"><span class="next">&#x203a;</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="slide_img" id="four">
     <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/MHZj0eb.jpg">
     <span class="caption">...................</span>
     <label class="lblp" for="i3"><span class="prev">&#x2039;</span></label>
     <label class="lbln" for="i1"><span class="next">&#x203a;</span></label>
   </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="text">...................................................</div>
      
   <a class="more" href="#" target="_blank">More</a>
 </div>
</div>
    
<div onclick="void(0);" class="tooltip2">Piediluco
 <div class="info2">
  <div class="container2">
    <input type="radio" id="i12" name="images2" checked>
    <input type="radio" id="i22" name="images2">
    <input type="radio" id="i32" name="images2">
    <input type="radio" id="i42" name="images2">
       
  <div class="slide_img2" id="one2">
    <img  class="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/S12ZVXY.jpg">
    <span class="caption2">.....................</span>
    <label class="lblp2" for="i32"><span class="prev2">&#x2039;</span></label>
    <label class="lbln2" for="i12"><span class="next2">&#x203a;</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_img2" id="two2">
    <img class="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/3JcEZp7.jpg">
    <span class="caption2">.....................</span>
    <label class="lblp2" for="i32"><span class="prev2">&#x2039;</span></label>
    <label class="lbln2" for="i12"><span class="next2">&#x203a;</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_img2" id="three2">
    <img class="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/kayLkDW.jpg">
    <span class="caption2">.....................</span>
    <label class="lblp2" for="i32"><span class="prev2">&#x2039;</span></label>
    <label class="lbln2" for="i12"><span class="next2">&#x203a;</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_img2" id="four2">
    <img class="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/gfRwbU2.jpg">
    <span class="caption2">.....................</span>
    <label class="lblp2" for="i32"><span class="prev2">&#x2039;</span></label>
    <label class="lbln2" for="i12"><span class="next2">&#x203a;</span></label>
  </div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="text2">...................................................</div>
      
  <a class="more2" href="#" target="_blank">More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I find the error/s?

Comment: This is probably too broad for Stack Overflow in its current form, and could do with cutting down to an [mcve]. Are you able to reproduce the issue with less code?

Comment: Since this is pure CSS, I guess you'd need to open your browser's element inspector and examine the HTML when you click on things. What HTML changes should happen on click, and what is not happening in the slideshow that is not working?

Comment: Ok snippet edited, now is a bit shorter. About the inspector...it shows no errors.

Comment: There is no need to add signatures, thanks, advance thanks, requests to help, how long one has been stuck, and so forth. We prefer succinct questions here.

Comment: I know, problem is my question had too much code and few words so your site didn't let me add my question.